# Rudin Exercice $2$ chapter $4$ Principles of Mathematical Analysis (PMA) - confusion about inclusion

Tags: general-topology, functions, continuity

I am having trouble understanding the solution to chapter $4$, exercice $2$ of Rudin's book.

Here is the solution: https://linearalgebras.com/baby-rudin-chapter-4a.html.

The part I don't understand is:

[image]

According to me, the set on the left should be included in the set on the right, instead.

The reason that makes me think that is that: $$V \supseteq f(E) \implies f^{-1}(V) \supseteq E$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is continuous and $V$ is closed, then $f^{-1}(V)$ is a closed set. If furthermore $f(E)\subset V$, then $E\subset f^{-1}(V)$ as you noted. Now, the closure of $E$ is *minimal* in the sense that it is the intersection of *all* closed sets containing $E$. By our first two remarks, the set on the left is an intersection of *some* closed sets containing $E$, so by minimality of the closure, $\bigcap_{W\supset E:W\ \text{closed}}W$ is a subset of the set on the left.

Answer (score 1):

For each closed set $V$ containing $f(E)$, we have $E \subseteq f^{-1}(f(E)) \subseteq f^{-1}(V)$ and $f^{-1}(V)$ is closed if $f$ is continous, then the right hand side is contained in each such $V$, hence the right hand side is contained in the left hand side.